# How to compute a dual basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

I have been searching everywhere for good resources (including other questions here) for understanding how to compute a dual basis given a basis in a vector space. Every single answer I found is confusing/doesn't explain how to actually work out a problem in full. Could somebody please help me understand the answer to the problem listed below. Where do these systems of equations that seem to spring out of nowhere come from? I understand it has something to do with the delta function but I am lost as to what the actual computation of going from the basis to the system of equations is. Please explain it in simple but thorough terms.

[image]

Comment: hi, could you also include how you defined the dual space, dual basis, and rougly what properties you know/are familiar with? This is so that we can provide an answer that is at an appropriate level with sufficient detail. Because knowing how much you know allows us to write better answers

Comment: Just FYI - $\delta_{ij}$ is called the "Kronecker delta", and it is something different (though remotely related) to the "delta function", which is denoted $\delta(t)$. The Kronecker delta is defined by $$\delta_{ij} = \begin{cases}1& i = j\\0& i\ne j\end{cases}$$ and is useful for writing several equations (9 in the example above) as one. The delta function is a "pseudo-function" (there isn't an actual one) with the properties that $\delta(t) = 0$ for $t\ne 0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t)f(t)\,dt = f(0)$ for continuous $f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's just focus on the first system, and use $e_j'$ to denote the dual basis elements (not standard, but it's used in the problem). We want to find the coordinates of $e_1'=(x_1\ y_1 \ z_2)$ so that $e_1'(e_1)=1,\ e_1'(e_2)=0,$ and $e_1'(e_1)=0$. You can either see this through using the standard basis and its dual basis or doing $e_1'e_j$ as row-column vector multiplication.

This gives the system of equations $$\begin{align*}x_1+y_1+2z_1&=1\\x_1+z_1&=0\\2x_1+y_1&=0. \end{align*}$$ Solving this system gives us $e_1'.$ Now, do the same for the other ones.

EDIT: I'll expand on computing, say, $e_1'(e_1)$. As I said, one way is to do the multiplication of these vectors ($e_1'$ is row and $e_1$ is a column). That's pretty straightforward and represents one way to get the first equation in the system.

Alternatively, we can write $e_1=f_1+f_2+2f_3$ and  $e_1'=x_1f_1'+y_1f_2'+z_1f_3'$ where $(f_j)$ and $(f_j)'$ denote the standard basis and its dual basis (respectively). Since $f_i'(f_j)=\delta_{ij}$, we know that $x_1f_1'(f_1)=x_1,\ x_1f_1'(f_2)=0,\ x_1f_1'(f_3)=0$, and then similarly for the other parts of $e_1',$ which will give us the first equation in the system.

Both of these ways are doing the same thing, but one may be more understandable for you right now. Eventually, you want to see these as the same.

Comment: That is where I am failing to understand. Why do we bring in the coordinates as the entries to the basis vectors? For example, I understand that e'1(e1) = 1 but why are do we use what I guess is just the dot product of e'1 and e1 on the left hand side of the first equation there?

Comment: @user208480 edited!

Comment: Okay that makes so much more sense. However, what are the f's supposed to represent? Is it just like standard basis vectors in a vector space? (like [1,0] is the first standard basis vector in R^2, here we would have [f_1, 0] or something?)

Comment: Yeah, they're just the standard basis. Here, they'll be $(1,0,0), (0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: I am still a little confused actually. Why are there two ways to calculate e'(e)? As in why are there even two sides to each equation in the system? Are we just defining e' and e (the vectors made up from basis vectors) to have the same behaviour as the f' and f basis vectors - as in are we defining them to also produce a delta function in order to get a system of equations?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, yes. By definition, the dual basis satisfies $e_i' (e_j)=\delta_{ij}.$ So, if we just consider $i=1,$ then we have three equations: $e_1'(e_1)=1, e_1'(e_2)=0,$ and $e_1'(e_3)=0.$ We find the left-hand sides of each of these equations in the manner that I showed in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The writer seems to use both the notation $e_i'$ and $e^i$ for the dual of $e_i$. Maybe this is the source of your confusion? The three systems of equations come from computing $e^je_i$ or $e_j'e_i$ (which is the same) for $j = 1,2,3$.

Answer (score 0):

The “delta function” that appears to be puzzling you is the Kronecker delta, which is defined by $$\delta_{ij} = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if }i=j, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$ Another way of putting this is that  $\delta_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$-th element of the identity matrix.

If we write the given basis vectors as *rows* of a matrix $B$ and the dual basis vectors as *columns* of $B'$, then the set of defining equations $e_ie^j=\delta_{ij}$ can be written as the single matrix equation $BB'=I$, from which $B'=B^{-1}$. Note that this only works because the bases in which both sets of vectors are expressed are themselves dual: the standard basis is its own dual.

In particular, for the basis in your question, $$B=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&2\\1&0&1\\2&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$B^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}-\frac13&\frac23&\frac13\\\frac23&-\frac43&\frac13\\\frac13&\frac13&-\frac13\end{bmatrix},$$ therefore $$e_1' = \left(-\frac13, \frac23, \frac13\right) \\ 
e_2' = \left(\frac23,-\frac43,\frac13\right) \\
e_3' = \left(\frac13,\frac13,-\frac13\right).$$

More generally, vectors aren’t always simply tuples of scalars, and their duals are more generally *linear functionals*—functions that take a vector and produce a scalar. You might not have a convenient pair of dual bases already so that you can use coordinate vectors to do this calculation, in which case you’ll need to fall back on the defining equation of a dual basis develop a system of equations for the dual basis. However, when you can express vectors and their duals as coordinates as above, then computing a dual basis amounts to finding the inverse transpose of a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

A last possibility would be using the cross product to build the dual basis:. Indeed the vectors defined as
$$\left(\frac{v_i\times v_j}{(v_i\times v_j)\cdot v_k}\right)^t\quad i\neq j\neq k$$
satisfy the conditions given: these are orthogonal to $v_i,v_j$ and have scalar product equal to $1$ with $v_k$